# How to hide an option dynamically with bootstrap-select

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap-select 1.7.2 and datepicker 1.7.1, I'm trying to change dynamically

```
<div class="check_availability-field">
   <label>Adultos</label>
   <select class="awe-select" name="adults">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="check_availability-field">
   <label>Niños</label>
   <select class="awe-select" name="children">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I tried with disabled,disabled class, deleting and adding, but bootstrap-select creates a dropdown of ul and li independent of my changes, is there any way to make the change dynamic?
I've been looking and I didn't see any solution, is there any way to achieve this or any alternative?

Comment: I was given a design made that way, the only way out is to change it and make it with more recent technology?
tx @Krampus